# Angular material svg icon cannot be loaded due to parsing error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to load a custom svg icon with angular material 7.2.0 and
angular v7.2.0

Therefore, I register the icon like

```
iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('box',
  sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/box.svg'));
```

Then I use the icon as

```
<mat-icon  svgIcon="box"></mat-icon>
```

but the icon is not showing.
In the console I can see the error `Error retrieving icon: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/assets/box.svg`.

I checked the code where the error is thrown and there I can see, that the error occurs in the stream returned from `iconRegistry.getNamedSvgIcon`, so I added the following code after registering the icon:

```
iconRegistry.getNamedSvgIcon('box')
.subscribe(res => console.log(res), err => console.error(err))
```

Now I can see, that the actual error contains `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, so it seems that angular is trying to parse the SVG as Json.

Is this a bug or did I misconfigure something? I also checked the headers of the response and the content type for SVG is correct.

Comment: Do you maybe use a `HttpInterceptor` that tries to parse every response as JSON?

Comment: Ha, you are actually right. I knew I had an interceptor and I even looked at it, but I only checked whether I was modifying the response, which was not the case. After having a closer look now, I saw that I changed the response type to JSON for every request. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

I have just modify your code,

The addSvgIcon registers our icon by taking-in 2 arguments, the first one being the icon label which is of type string.

The second argument is the relative URL path pointing to the location of the icon. This is of type SafeResourceUrl. To parse the url path string into SafeResourceUrl, we can make use of the DomSanitizer provided by Angular.

import

```
import { MatIconRegistry } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

In constructor

```
  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
     this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
     "meeting",
    this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/meetingicon.svg")
    );
  }
```

Html

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="meeting"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question!

Answer (score 0):

For SSR, full URL is needed in order to retrieve svg icon.
When encountered to this issue, I fixed it with something like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string, @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) protected request: Request) {
    const svgUrl = 'assets/Icons/loader-default.svg';
    // domain and port for SSR in this example is static. Use i.e. environment files to use appropriate dev/prod domain:port
    const domain = request && isPlatformServer(platformId) ?
  `${request.protocol}:${request.get('host')}/` : ''; 
    this._matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('loader', this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(domain + svgUrl));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```